# How to record screen on andriod

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, screen, screen-sharing, screencast

I want record screen on my andriod phone. Without root permission. How can i do that. ( Galaxy s3 mini. Jelly bean. )

Answer (score -1):

Try [easy screen recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.org.invisibility.recordablefree) no root

Comment: Just in case you want to try it first, [this is the free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.org.invisibility.recordablefree).